# FieldLookupValue fails conversion

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, conversion

**Setup**

- 2 lists, linked by a lookup in one of the lists
- CamlQuery to get items together with fields from other list (projectedfields)

**Problem**

When I retreive the listitems with the CAMLQuery, it works. All correct listitems are returned. But when I try to convert the ProjectedFields, it fails and throws an error (see below)

**Error**

> The type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll' and
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'

**Code**

```
var foo = (FieldLookupValue)listItem["bar"]
```

**Type**

When I'm in debugmode and try to get the type of the field (immediate window):

```
listItem["bar"].GetType()
```

> {Name = "FieldLookupValue" FullName =
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"}
>       [System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "FieldLookupValue" FullName = "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"}
>       base: {Name = "FieldLookupValue" FullName = "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"}
>       Assembly: {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.3912.1204, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c}
>       AssemblyQualifiedName: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.3912.1204, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
>       Attributes: Public | BeforeFieldInit
>       BaseType: {Name = "ClientValueObject" FullName = "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientValueObject"}
>       ContainsGenericParameters: false
>       DeclaringMethod: 'listItem["bar"].GetType().DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       DeclaringType: null
>       FullName: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"
>       GenericParameterAttributes: 'listItem["bar"].GetType().GenericParameterAttributes' threw an
>   exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       GenericParameterPosition: 'listItem["bar"].GetType().GenericParameterPosition' threw an
>   exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       GenericTypeArguments: {System.Type[0]}
>       GUID: {601ca347-ae93-3db5-ac96-5aa71e30632f}
>       HasElementType: false
>       IsAbstract: false
>       IsAnsiClass: true
>       IsArray: false
>       IsAutoClass: false
>       IsAutoLayout: true
>       IsByRef: false
>       IsClass: true
>       IsCOMObject: false
>       IsConstructedGenericType: false
>       IsContextful: false
>       IsEnum: false
>       IsExplicitLayout: false
>       IsGenericParameter: false
>       IsGenericType: false
>       IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
>       IsImport: false
>       IsInterface: false
>       IsLayoutSequential: false
>       IsMarshalByRef: false
>       IsNested: false
>       IsNestedAssembly: false
>       IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
>       IsNestedFamily: false
>       IsNestedFamORAssem: false
>       IsNestedPrivate: false
>       IsNestedPublic: false
>       IsNotPublic: false
>       IsPointer: false
>       IsPrimitive: false
>       IsPublic: true
>       IsSealed: false
>       IsSecurityCritical: false
>       IsSecuritySafeCritical: false
>       IsSecurityTransparent: true
>       IsSerializable: false
>       IsSpecialName: false
>       IsUnicodeClass: false
>       IsValueType: false
>       IsVisible: true
>       MemberType: TypeInfo
>       Module: {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll}
>       Namespace: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client"
>       ReflectedType: null
>       StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
>       TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
>       TypeInitializer: null
>       UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "FieldLookupValue" FullName = "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"}

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
FieldUserValue fuv = (FieldUserValue)item["FIELD_NAME"];
fuv.LookupValue.ToString()
```